# azure storage blob container name - separate for each user/owner

Tags: azure-storage

In order to keep the blob storage separated per user in a multiuser application, i was trying to create separate containers per user within the same storage account. I know it can hit a 500TB limit at some point, but thats for later.

I was thinking of using:
ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value
as the name of the container but looks like its not allowed and violating the container naming conventions. Since i am using it to differentiate user specific data in sql tables i was thinking if using the same. But doesnt seem to work.

Any recommendations? Whats the cleanest way?

Comment: Could you update your question to give an example of a name that didn't work? With some minor modifications this may be a usable value but it's hard for us to say if we don't know what these values look like

Comment: Looks like ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier) contains some characters which are in Capitals and this is not allowed for a <container-name>. Can i just lower case all the characters? Will this still preserve the Uniqueness?

Answer (score 1):

Are you saying you don't know the naming conventions? If not, then, as 
Emily suggested, you should update your question to show the example names that you're trying to use. However, if you don't know the naming conventions, please refer to the [naming rules section in How to use Blob Storage](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs/#naming-and-referencing-containers-and-blobs).

Comment: Hi @Michael!! Can you please check this? http://stackoverflow.com/q/35089955/1147273