# Create a container storage in Azure for each user

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

My question is simple, I have a web app where the users can upload photos and other stuff...

Is a good practice create a container storage in Azure for each user in my application?

My web app, now have about 40K users. I need to get the size total of the uploaded content user and I work with CDN too, but it's growing about 10K users/month.

If the user pass the limit of 20Mb, I need to send an email informing the user about it.

Now, in Amazon S3, we have just one bucket, and I am using "folders" for each user.

Thanks!!

Comment: In general, it is very difficult to write a question that asks "Is this a good practice" without it being completely subjective.

Comment: I know, but I would like to know if I would have any limitation or problem with CDN or whatever ;)

Comment: what sort of problem? Like running out of space, for example?  that kind of question needs more information, particularly the number of users you anticipate having.  It seems like you could expand at least a little bit about what your concerns are, rather than just asking a completely open ended "is it possible something might not be good".

Comment: @chemitaxis - your question didn't ask about limitations. It asked about organizing content in one container vs many (and that's purely opinion - whichever way you want to do it).

Comment: Thanks David, any limitations between these options? Limit of containers? Size of them? CDN configuratiin?

Comment: This is all documented. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-scalability-targets/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question will be based on opinion. However, it is possible to create one container and create virtual directories for each user, if you'd like to go that route. You can learn more about that here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs/#naming-and-referencing-containers-and-blobs